# How to get correct shape of predict model?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

The Model is used to predict future's height, weight with lstm.

My Dataset Example

Train X :

```html
 <table border="1">
    <th>Height(cm)</th>
    <th>Weight(kg)</th>
    <tr>
        <td>180</td>
        <td>88</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>181</td>
        <td>77</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>182</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td>183</td>
        <td>79</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Train Y :

```html
<table border="1">
        <th>Height(cm)</th>
        <th>Weight(kg)</th>
        <tr>
            <td>182</td>
            <td>86</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

This is just example
I changed the dataset to 3d with these code

```
xtrain= np.reshape(xtrain,(xtrain.shape[0],xtrain.shape[1],2))
```

The result : xtrain.shape = (82, 4, 2)
ytrain.shape = (82, 1, 2)

Then, this is model.summary()

```
Model: "sequential"

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 4, 50)             10600     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 4, 50)             20200     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 4, 50)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 4, 2)              102       
=================================================================
Total params: 30,902
Trainable params: 30,902
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I want the model output's to be (None, 1, 2)

How It should be changed??

```
model=Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',input_shape=(xtrain.shape[1],2)))

model.add(LSTM(units=50,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',return_sequences=True))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(units=2))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')

model.fit(xtrain,ytrain,batch_size=4,epochs=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you experimente with flatten layer? from the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/flatten/):

> Note: If inputs are shaped (batch,) without a feature axis, then flattening adds an extra channel dimension and output shape is (batch, 1).